# How to combine a subscription and single payments in one charge [Stripe API]?

Tags: stripe-payments

In a purchase there might be a situation where a user may be purchasing both a subscription and some single payment items. If possible, I would like to process them as a single charge to avoid a potential situation, where the subscription succeeds and the single item purchase fails and other issues like that.

From what research I have done on this, there is no specific endpoint in the Stripe API for combining a subscription. The idea is to combine all the initial subscription and single purchase payments into a single payment intent and, once paid, to create subscriptions with trials and process individual payment items? Is this the approach to use currently or is there something newer / better, that I have missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this be leveraging `add_invoice_items` when [creating the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#first-invoice-extra):

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions \
  -u sk_test_123: \
  -d customer="{{ CUSTOMER_ID }}" \
  -d "items[0][price]={{ RECURRING_PRICE_ID }}" \
  -d "add_invoice_items[0][price]={{ PRICE_ID }}"
```

If you want to [add extra one-time charge to future renewal invoices](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#adding-upcoming-invoice-items), you can create additional invoice items for that Customer (and Subscription).

Comment: Thank you, will test it out for my use case and, if it works in this case, will give the accepted answer.